# How to change the ending of a line in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there a way to change the shape of a line ending by choosing an angle with Adobe Illustrator?

Making something like this:

[image]

I know that you can do this with a square, but if there is a solution to do the exact same thing with a line! :D

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use calligraphic brushes if you want the angle to be relative to document.

[image]

No, you can not do this if you want it to be relative to the curve. You can fudge it so that the line has a slanted edge but then the line itself has to go past the point your now at (line has to be past the poits tangency). Or you can put a clipping mask around it. Or you can make a custom arrow. Or you can expand and skew inside a effect, But again this couldn't account for the orientation of the line.